# EntityFramework Core 5 não conecta ao SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu, .net-core, entity-framework-5

Instalei o dotnet core 5 no ubuntu 21.04. Criei um projeto webapi com VS Code e consegui rodar tudo tranquilo.

Instalei o EF5 ao projeto e estou tentando me conectar ao SQL Server 2008

**DbContext**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Models
{
    public partial class Banco : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }
        public Banco() : base()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=<<servidor>>; Database=<<banco>>; User Id=<<user>>; Password=<<senha>>;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Cliente>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.codcli });

        }

    }

}
```

**Model**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Models
{
    public partial class Cliente
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int codcli { get; set; }

        public string nomcli { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;

namespace dotnetc_webapi.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("")]
    public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public dynamic Get()
        {
            Models.Banco banco = new Models.Banco();
            var cliente = banco.Cliente.Take(10).Select(cli => cli).ToArray();
            return new OkObjectResult(cliente);

        }
    }
}
```

Ao rodar o projeto com o comando **dotnet watch run** ele abre o navegador e ao tentar conectar ao banco apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
SqlException: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)
```

na linha `var cliente = banco.Cliente.Take(10).Select(cli => cli).ToArray();`

O que eu acho estranho é que se eu pegar o mesmo projeto sem qualquer alteração no código e rodar dentro do Windows 10 ele consegue conectar ao banco e receber os dados dos clientes normalmente e no ubuntu não.

Já tentei esse procedimentos e nada
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux

Não sei se esta é a forma correta ou eu estou deixando passar algo.

Estou na dependência do windows só por causa deste projeto, tenho que usar uma VM para rodar o windows por causa dele. Gostaria muito de resolver esse problema e ficar somente usando o linux.

Comment: e como esta conectando ao banco, com IP, nome? já testou a mesma conexão em outro client, no management studio por exmplo?

Comment: Eu uso um domínio ddns.net para conectar ao servidor. Se eu usar no Windows o projeto consegue conectar ao banco e receber os dados. No Ubuntu usando dotnet não funciona. Dentro do Ubuntu eu uso outro client o navicat e ele consegue conectar normalmente.